# Java don't know where to start on this method for a periodic table

Tags: java, class, methods, static, instance

So i'm having issue on understanding how to go about starting a method for `findAbbreviation(atomic #)`. Every time I try to use `table[]` in another method it gives me a non-static variable issue. Please share any tips on how to go about starting this method that will return the reference to the element with abbreviation.

```
public class PeriodicTable {
    private final static int MAX_ELEMENTS = 150;

    private PeriodicElement[] table;
    private int actualSize;

    public PeriodicTable () throws IOException {
            table = new PeriodicElement[MAX_ELEMENTS];

            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("/user/tvnguyen7/data/periodictable.dat"));
            int index = 0;
            while(input.hasNext() && index < MAX_ELEMENTS) {
                    int aN = input.nextInt();
                    String abbr = input.next();
                    String name = input.next();
                    double aW = input.nextDouble();
                    table[index] = new PeriodicElement(aN, abbr,name, aW);
                    index++;
            }
            input.close();
            actualSize = index;
    }


public void printTable () throws IOException {
            final int MAX_ELEMENTS = 118;

            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("/user/tvnguyen7/data/periodictable.dat"));

            int[] atomicNumbers = new int[MAX_ELEMENTS];
            double[] atomicWeights = new double[MAX_ELEMENTS];

            for(int i=0;i<atomicNumbers.length;i++) {
                    atomicNumbers[i]= input.nextInt();
                    String abbreviation = input.next();
                    String name = input.next();
                    atomicWeights[i] = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.printf("%4d  %-4s    %-25s   %.2f\n" , atomicNumbers[i], abbreviation, name, atomicWeights[i]);
            }
            input.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not given the complete signature of `findAbbreviation` method, but I guess you are trying to make it static. 
Use following method:

```
public String findAbbreviation(int atomicNumber)
{
    // code...
}
```

Also, just a tip, its not a good practice to have logic in constructor.
Thanks!